# Software Sources not found in Unity Dash Search

Tags: unity-dash, software-sources

After upgrading to 12.04 from 11.10, I am no longer able to find Software Sources in Dash.  I have installed software-properties-gtk, and can open via terminal, but cannot get Dash to find it? Is this still possible? I want to be able to go direct to my sources without having to load Synaptic or Software Center. What I have done now is launched from terminal, and then pinned to launcher, but typing in dash still does not find it.

Comment: There's another way here, that will enable it for everyone (red section) : http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-edit-dash-application-results/

Answer (score 9):

First copy the software sources desktop file to your local applications folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
cp /usr/share/applications/software-properties-gtk.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Edit the file:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/software-properties-gtk.desktop
```

change the line `NoDisplay=true` to `NoDisplay=false`

Save, logout and login.

[image]

Comment: I updated from 11.10 to 12.04 too. I tried the workflow above. There was not NoDisplay row in the software-properties-gtk.desktop file (I edited the original one). I insert it to the end with the value False. I started Ubuntu again. There is not any result.

Answer (score 5):

You can do following steps for showing "Software Source" program in Unity search result:

1. Install "Main Menu" program from software center(package name is "alacarte").
2. Run "Main Menu" program.
3. From right panel called "Menus" open "System Tools" node and select "Preference" node.
4. Check "Software Source" in next pane.
5. Finish, in next login you will see Unity "Software Source" in search result

[image]