# Couldn't find software sources and uninstalled and got message about future updates 12.04

Tags: system, software-sources

Software sources wasn't showing up in the unity menu when I searched for it but it said it was installed in the software center.  I uninstalled it and got the message:

> **If you uninstall Software Sources, future updates will not include new items in The Ubuntu desktop system set. Are you sure you want to
>   continue?**
>
> **Install Packages using the apt protocol**
>
> apturl
>
> **The ubuntu desktop system**
>
> ubuntu-desktop

I reinstalled it and still couldint find it.

I found the answer here
[Software Sources not found in Unity Dash Search](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131452/software-sources-not-found-in-unity-dash-search-after-upgrade-to-12-04)

So now I have it back, but im afraid that since I initially uninstalled it that I'm going to not get the "future updates" even thought I reinstalled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you have the package *ubuntu-desktop* installed. The message above is actually caused by removing that package. It depends on *Software sources* and so it got removed when you removed *Software sources*.

Comment: Ok ubuntu-desktop got uninstalled, but I reinstalled it, am I all set now?

Comment: Yes. *ubuntu-desktop* is just a package that makes sure that everything that belongs to the Ubuntu standard desktop is installed. So as long as *ubuntu-desktop* is installed you are sure to have everything that belongs to the standard desktop.