# Ubuntu 12.04 won't recognize my graphics driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

I've installed nvidia current (it works mostly) but the details section of the system settings shows that my driver is standard and the version is unknown.  I'm getting a lot of errors and compiz has crashed at least twice.

Any help?  What other information should I provide?

Comment: You said "installed Nvidia current",Right?.How did you install it? By "Additional Drivers" option? If so,make sure to install the one "recommended".

Comment: Yes I installed the recommended version through the driver gui originally but it gave me a black screen.  So I purged the driver and reinstalled through the terminal with: sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Answer (score 3):

Just enter

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

and voila, it shows it as recognized.

Comment: Firstly welcome to the AskUbuntu site! To further help the original poster of the question above I'd add more useful information to complement your answer if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my software sources settings to reflect the settings given. To do this I had to change the download from setting on the ubuntu software tab from 'netherlands' to 'Main server'. In addition to this I had to check the pre released updates (precise-proposed) check box on the updates tab. This gave an additional 60 updates but none of these mentioned nvidia. I installed them anyhow and a reboot was requested. After this reboot there are still no proprietary drivers found and the graphics information in the settings still says 'Driver Unknown, Experience Standard'

update:

the problem is mostly solved by performing the steps found on: [mygeekopinions.blogspot on how to install nvidia drivers](http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-install-nvidia-2750907-driver-in.html)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

After a reboot the additional drivers dialog shows the nvidia proprietary drivers. The graphic settings section of the all settings details window however still shows 'Driver unknown, Experience Standard'.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You've posted this as an answer, but it's not an attempt to answer the original poster's question, so it [may be deleted soon](http://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion). It looks like you have a separate, related question about how to get this to work on your machine. If that is the case, you should [post a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You may also want to "star" this question, to be notified of any new answers. Alternatively, if this *is* intended as an answer, you may want to reword it so that this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, now doing all the updates after I checked all the configuration you showed through the software sources, which I had to find first (was not visible) and I did thanks to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131452/software-sources-not-found-in-unity-dash-search).

I did all the updates, still graphics unknown. don't know what else to do, I tried everything, NVIDIA has a massive issue here with ubuntu.

if you get the updates someone recommend you end up with a 640x480 resolution, then you have the xorg problem, seems there's no solution to this problem.